# Mongo update not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have this model:

```
var stuffSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  "id": 1,
  "cars": {
    "suv": [],
    "sports": [],
    "supercar": [{
      "owner": "nick",
      "previousOwners": [
        ObjectId("574e1bc0abfb4a180404b17f"),
        ObjectId("574e1bdeabfb4a180404b180"),
        ObjectId("574e1c4babfb4a180404b181"),
        ObjectId("574e1c67abfb4a180404b182"),
        ObjectId("574e23abd25baf340e678b2d"),
        ObjectId("574e241ec8caa3a81cc85ed5")
      ]
    }]
  }
});

var Stuff = mongoose.model('Stuff', stuffSchema);
```

I want to add a `previousOwners` if a specific `owner` already exists and add a new `owner` **with** its respective `previousOwner` if the specific `owner` does not exist yet.

Here's what I tried:

```
Stuff.update({
  id: 1,
  'cars.supercar.owner': 'olix'
}, {
  $addToSet: {
    'cars.supercar.$.previousOwners': ObjectId("574e241ec8caa3a81c893e73")
  }
}, {
  $upsert: true
}, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
  }
});
```

I expected this to add a new `owner` called 'olix' accompanied by its `previousOwners` array. That would make my document look like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "cars": {
    "suv": [],
    "sports": [],
    "supercar": [{
      "owner": "nick",
      "previousOwners": [
        ObjectId("574e1bc0abfb4a180404b17f"),
        ObjectId("574e1bdeabfb4a180404b180"),
        ObjectId("574e1c4babfb4a180404b181"),
        ObjectId("574e1c67abfb4a180404b182"),
        ObjectId("574e23abd25baf340e678b2d"),
        ObjectId("574e241ec8caa3a81cc85ed5")
      ],
      "owner": "olix",
      "previousOwners": [
        ObjectId("574e241ec8caa3a81c893e73")
      ]
    }]
  }
}
```

It's not working at all. It's not even yielding an error.
I tried:

```
db.stuffs.find({id: 1, 'cars.supercar.owner': 'nick'})
```

and it returns the document successfully. Just to be sure that my query is correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your expected `supercar[0]` has duplicate keys. It's impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by manually updating with:

```
Stuff.findOne({
  id: 1
}, function(err, stuff) {
  if (err) {
    return done(err);
  }

  var ownersList = stuff.cars.supercar.map(function(supercarCar) {
    return supercarCar.owner;
  });

  var ownerIndex = ownersList.indexOf('nick');

  if (ownerIndex != -1) {
    stuff.cars.supercar[ownerIndex].previousOwners.push(ObjectId("574e241ec8caa3a81c893e73"));
  } else {
    stuff.cars.supercar.push({
      owner: 'nick',
      previousOwners: [ObjectId("574e241ec8caa3a81c893e73")]
    })
  }

  stuff.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }
  });
});
```

**Notes**
This is a fake document, all property names were changed for anonymity. 
The **done** function is used here because this code is being ran in a **.pre('save'** instance of the schema.
Some values are hard coded just for example purpose.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your schema definition is incorrect use this instead:

```
var stuffSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    'id': Number,
    'cars': {
        'suv': [],
        'sports': [],
        'supercar': [{
            _id: false,
            'owner': { type: String },
            'previousOwners': [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId }]
        }]
    }
});

var Stuff = mongoose.model('Stuff', stuffSchema);
```

Change update query to this:

```
Stuff.update({ 
    id: 1
}, {
    $addToSet: {
        'cars.supercar': {
            'owner': 'olix',
            'previousOwners': [ObjectId('574e241ec8caa3a81c893e75')]
        }
    }
}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    }
});
```

note: mongoose checks each property of object, so supercar array object is same if it's owner field and previousOwners array is exactly same, otherwise it will push new object into supercar array.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I meant to show just the document, not the model. The query you gave me satisfied one of my expectations: **add a new `owner` with its respective `previousOwners` if `owner` didn't exist yet**, but it doesn't satisfy the **add `previousOwners` where `owner` already exists**. I forgot to mention in my schema `owner` is **unique**

Comment: @Troy you can not add unique index in embed document field, so this code won't work: `'owner': { type: String, index: { unique: true } }`. 
Unique indexes exist only across collection. You need at least two queries to achieve what you want:
1) find document using `id` and check this document `supercar` array if contains object with same owner. You can use `lodash` or `underscore` to do this faster. If object exists do nothing if not push new object into array and go to second query 2) `$set` new supercar arrray to selceted object and save edited document.